# Shouldn't these two loops produce the same result?

Tags: java

I was solving a programming problem where you get an input and you have to add every number from 1 - input to the input for example lets say the input 
 is 5 :5+4+3+2+1 = 15.

To solve this  I tried these two for loops below.

```
    //This loop worked for most inputs
     int input = 12 ;
     for(int i = input - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      input += i;
     }          
       System.out.println(input);

      //This just produced a negative number
       int input2 = 12;
       for(int i = 1; i < input2;i++){
           input2  += i;

       }
       System.out.println(input2);
```

Only one loop worked although the seem like they should produce the same result can anyone explain?

Comment: You should debug this code and look in every iteration how `input` changes.

Comment: The first loop starts at `input-1` (11) and goes down until zero. The second loop starts at 1 and goes up to `input2` —  but `input2` increases each time through the loop. So the loop will go on for a lot longer.

Comment: Loop 1 worked for _most_ inputs??

Comment: You should not use a variable named `input`, containing the input, to store the **output** of your algorithm.

Comment: In general, you should try to avoid modifying variables which are used to constrain for-loops, **inside the loops themselves**. Unless you *really really need to* this will greatly complicate your program logic. Try to format your adding loops as follows: 1.) an incremented variable `i` which changes on each iteration, 2.) a constant upper or lower bound `cons` which constrains `i`, e.g. `i < cons`, and 3.) a variable `sum` which is changed by the body of the loop on each iteration

Comment: Sorry Loop 1 works for all inputs actually i made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Errors are pretty nicely defined in previous answers, I'm just going to add the following:

This could also be solved using ArrayList and summing its members with loop, but it would be an overkill.
That gives you ability to remove/change values of the list you iterating through using Java Iterator class.
As I said before, this solution is overkill for such task, but it could be interesting to research.

More of Java Iterator: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html